# Makefile: Copying files with a rule

Tags: makefile

I am trying to copy files using a my rule but my rule does not get triggered:

```
BUILDDIR = build
COPY_FILES = code/xml/schema/schema.xsd config.txt

all: $(BUILDDIR) $(COPY_FILES) copy

$(BUILDDIR):
    mkdir -p $@

$(COPY_FILES):
    cp -f $@ $(BUILDDIR)

copy:
    cp -f $(COPY_FILES) $(BUILDDIR)
```

I am trying to use $(COPY_FILES) but it is not being triggered, although $(BUILDDIR) and copy are triggered. I am not sure what is wrong with my Makefile. I would like to get the $(COPY_FILES) rule to work if possible please (and remove copy). Does anyone please know?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The problem with the `$(COPY_FILES)` rule is that the targets of that rule are two files that already exist, namely `code/xml/schema/schema.xsd` and `config.txt`. Make sees no reason to execute the rule. <strike>I'm not sure why Make doesn't execute the `copy` rule, but I suspect that there's a file called `copy` confusing the matter.</strike> Anyway, [copy] a bad rule.

Try this:

```
COPY_FILES = $(BUILD_DIR)/schema.xsd $(BUILD_DIR)/config.txt

all: $(COPY_FILES)

$(BUILD_DIR)/schema.xsd: code/xml/schema/schema.xsd
$(BUILD_DIR)/config.txt: config.txt

$(BUILD_DIR)/%:
    cp -f $< $@
```

Comment: He said copy is being triggered but that doesn't change the fact that it is a badly written rule.

Comment: @Beta How would you approach this if the files to be copied were in a `src/` directory and changed periodically? E.g., what if you can't explicitly list all of the files that need to be copied, and instead build them with `$(wildcard)`?

Comment: @PeterT: No problem: `COPY_FILES := $(patsubst src/%,build/%,$(wildcard src/*))` and for the final rule `$(BUILD_DIR)/%: $(SRC_DIR)/%`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I use a simple "for loop" to cp all those files.

For examples, write the rule as following:

```
RELEASE_DIR = ../rc1
RELEASE_FILES = ai.h main.cc main_async.cc bmp_utils.h bmp_utils.cc
release: $(RELEASE_FILES)
     for u in $(RELEASE_FILES); do echo $$u; cp -f $$u $(RELEASE_DIR); done
```

Then,

```
make release
```