# copying only changed files between directories using Makefile

Tags: makefile

I read this: [Makefile: Copying files with a rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18091538/makefile-copying-files-with-a-rule) but couldn't do it.
To make it simple, suppose I have two directories dir1 and dir2. Under dir1 I have three files: rabbit.c, tiger.c and bus.c .
I made Makefile like this:

```
dir2/rabbit.c:dir1/rabbit.c
dir2/tiger.c:dir1/tiger.c
dir2/bike.c:dir1/bike.c

dir2/%:
    cp -f $< $@
```

I specified the prerequisites in three separate lines and specified the unified recipe for the three targets. I expected when I touch any file under dir1, `make` will copy that file to dir2. But this happend only for rabbit.c. What is wrong?

---

ADD(after selecting an answer) : 
After realizing what's wrong by Takkat's answer, I fixed it and later modified it further and I think this is the correct simplest Makefile for this case.

```
.PHONY:all
LIST:=rabbit.c tiger.c bike.c
DSTFILES:=$(addprefix dir2/, $(LIST))
all: $(DSTFILES)

dir2/%:dir1/%
    cp -f $< $@
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make chooses a default target in your makefile and, unless you specify differently on the command line, it builds just that target (and all prerequisites required to build that target).

The default target in a makefile is, by default, the first explicit target listed.

So in your makefile the first rule is:

```
dir2/rabbit.c:dir1/rabbit.c
```

so the first explicit target is `dir2/rabbit.c`, so that's all make builds.

If you want to build multiple targets by default, you need a first target that lists all the "real" targets as prerequisites; put this line first in your makefile:

```
all: dir2/rabbit.c dir2/tiger.c dir2/bike.c
```

and it will work.  It's often considered good practice to declare targets like this, which don't relate to real files on the disk, as phony:

```
.PHONY: all
```

Comment: Oh, I forgot this basic again. Thanks! (I don't know if I forgot this `first target is the default target` rule or I didn't really understand it. Maybe the later, that's why I miss this basic rule..)

Comment: Yes, it works. just I tried using `all: $(addprefix dir2/, rabbit.c tiger.c bike.c)` to make it look more stylish :)